# Substitute for UDC, Usage Data Collector?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Since UDC is [no longer supported](http://wiki.eclipse.org/UDC) or part of the Eclipse, I'm wondering if there is a substitute. I'd like to get more information regarding how our set of users are actually using Eclipse in order to be proactive and try to improve their environment.

Things I'd like to gather:

- Perspectives used
- Views used
- Errors reported
- Eclipse version/type used
- JVM used

This should be possible to upload to a private server.

I could of course use the UDC and possible change the code if needed, but I'd rather use an existing and supported plugin if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is to adopt the UDC code and change it for your needs. Or you might want to see what happend to [this prototype](http://www.codetrails.com/blog/developers-guide-eclipse-calling-home-policy-part-i).

Regarding error reporting there was also a discussion going on on the Eclipse ide-dev mailing list that might be of interest:

https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/ide-dev/msg00602.html

https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/ide-dev/msg00596.html