# Catch any Eclipse IDE event

Tags: java, eclipse, events, eclipse-plugin, event-handling

I have a plugin in my working group, which shows last activities made on a shared project (like version control, but with more features specific to our group). And I want to display current actions, like what the user is doing (opening dialogs, focusing views, editing, opening package explorer, refactoring, searching and so on).

Is there a general mechanism to catch any kind of event in Eclipse? I mean, is there a 'global' event creator or something, on which I can listen and get any kind of event?

Answer (score 1):

It appears so. I haven't used it myself, but there seems to be an Eventbus that you can use. All Eclipse/osig events pass through it. There is a tutorial about it [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4EventSystem/article.html) and a wikipage [there](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Event_Model).

Not sure exactly what kind of events you will catch there. I doubt it will be as specific as those examples you listed. For that, it sounds like you want UDC, Usage Data Collector, which was discontinued in eclipse 3.5/3.6. Seems like there is [no alternative available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204844/substitute-for-udc-usage-data-collector).